# When using declarative syntax, is there a way to avoid separate stages for each "when" condition?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to avoid creating a separate stage for each conditional "when" statement ? In other words, in the example below, the maven command is exactly the same for the two branches except for one parameter.

So, is there an easier way to have a single stage called 'maven build' with a conditional execution based on the branch that is being built. Apart from the tedious duplication, a side effect of this is that in Jenkins, the "stage" view becomes longer and longer.

```
       pipeline{
       :
       :
       stage('Maven Build (develop)'){
        when{
            branch 'develop'
        }
         steps {
                // Do these steps 
              }
          }

    stage('Maven Build (release)'){
        when{
            branch 'releases/**'
        }
          steps {
                // Do same steps as in the previous Maven Build but 
                // with a minor change. 
          }
        }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pipeline {

    stage('Maven build') {
        steps {
            echo "Build on branch ${env.GIT_BRANCH}"
            // do the same steps

            script {
                if(env.GIT_BRANCH.startsWith("releases")) {
                    // do the diff steps only for non-develop branch
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's `env.BRANCH_NAME` in my Jenkins `/pipeline-syntax/globals`